# equalHeight on Shortest Column jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery implementation to have equalHeight on the tallest column, but in this scenario i don't want the columns to match the tallest. The idea is to make col2 and col3 match the height of col1. I have an overflow:auto applied to all the columns so a scrollbar will appear.

See demo, but this equalHeight matches the tallest column, but I'd like the reverse to happen
http://jsfiddle.net/L7JvD/2/

```
   $.fn.equalHeightify = function() {
        var highest = 0; // keep track of the greatest height
        $(this).each(function() { // for each element
            if ($(this).height() > highest) { // compare heights
                highest = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $(this).height(highest); // set new height
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.column').equalHeightify();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In light of the updated question, the below is more to your needs.

```
$.fn.equalHeightify = function(ColNumber) {
    var targetCol = ColNumber - 1; // Substracing one because .each() uses a zero-based index, so Column 1 = index 0, etc.
    var targetHeight = $(this).eq(targetCol).height(); // grab the target item's height
    $(this).each(function(index) { // for each element
        if (index != targetCol) // find all items besides the target column and set their height to the target column's height
            $(this).height(targetHeight);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.column').equalHeightify(2);
});
```

This revised version allows you to specify the column number that you want to use as the target to size all others against. To test in the jsFiddle, change the number on the `equalHeightify()` call to whichever you want.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5N42p/4/

<strike>Pretty straightforward; change the logic to set an initial lowest value then compare all subsequent column heights to that - whenever a new lower one is found, reset the value to its height:</strike>

```
$.fn.equalHeightify = function () {
    var lowest; // keep track of the lowest height
    $(this).each(function (index) { // for each element
        if (index == 0) // set the height of the first item as our initial "lowest"
            lowest = $(this).height();
        else if ($(this).height() < lowest) // compare all other's heights to "lowest" and reset "lowest" if a shorter is found
            lowest = $(this).height();
    });
    $(this).height(lowest); // set new height
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9v3n/2/

Comment: Hmmm. this works, because it's matching the smallest (very clever) however I'd like to be able to target the smallest with a class and make the other columns match it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - as part of the function execution, do you just need to apply an `.addClass()` to the shortest element?

Comment: my fault for the poor description. your  approach is smart, because you're matching the shortest column technically the center column in this case, but if I wanted to match the first column (which isn't as short) but I wanted all columns to match it. That's what I mean.

Comment: If you want all the columns to assume the height of the first item in the collection, this will do that: http://jsfiddle.net/8AucL/1/

Comment: I tested that and it works. Very nice. However, if I wanted all of a sudden the third column or the fifth column to be the master and the other columns to be the slave then would I do then? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Give me a minute; I'll need to modify the jsFiddle & my answer to include the passing of a parameter when calling `equalHeightify` to specify the column number that you want to use to set the height of all other columns.